# How can i see Goerli Testnet NFT, in PC browser?

Tags: nft, testnets, goerli

I'm testing NFT creation on goerli testnet.

All works fine, I can also see the final minted NFT on Metamask mobile...

I cannot find a way to see it on a PC....

I have the NFT contract address, the NFT #, but I have not found so far a way to see it in a web browser on a PC....

Anybody can suggest a solution?

Thank you all

Comment: Did you try testnets.opensea.io?

Answer (score 0):

try this one. https://www.nftviewer.xyz/ put the contract address and the tokenid of the nft you want to see[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you shared the contract address and the transaction-id while minting

You can try this, login to the opensea testnet the https://testnets.opensea.io using the metamask wallet used for mintnig.
Visit this link and you should see your nft here. https://testnets.opensea.io/collections